# Cordova app issue with photo plugin returning to blank screen

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created an app using cordova and have included the photo plugin.  I am trying to run it on iOS 10 and am experiencing a blank white screen when returning from using the plugin.

The app loads OK, I have a simple button that calls getPicture(...); This bit also works OK, the camera on the device appears and all appears well.  However, the issue I am experiencing is when I return from taking a photo or even if I choose cancel, the app returns to a blank white screen.

It is like the app is not bringing the WebView to the foreground successfully when returning from the camera.  Any ideas?

I am not seeing any errors in Xcode or when using the Safari remote debugger.  The see the success function call from the camera plugin getPicture() method is being called and executed, but the screen is blank. I think something is in the foreground, but can't tell.  Can anybody help?

Is there a way to force the WebView to the front when the plugin finishes operation or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: are you using the cordova-plugin-statusbar?

Comment: yes, is there a known issue with this plugin?

Comment: @user2952247 Please mark the answer below as accepted, it definitely fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug in cordova-plugin-statusbar

It's fixed in master, so you can install the plugin from the github repo or wait until it's released.

To install from github:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar`

Answer (score 1):

I removed the plugin for statusbar and now it seems to work.  There was a strange issue with the landscape orientation.